# Composer's autoload has no classmap

Tags: php, composer-php

I'm loading this repo:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php": "*@dev"
    }
}
```

But the generated classmap is empty, and I can't use the repo:

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
);
```

What is wrong with my composer.json setup?

PS: I ran `update`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to configure the autoload option for the repository like this:

```
{
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "package",
            "package": {
                "name": "ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php",
                "version": "master",
                "source": {
                    "url": "https://github.com/ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php.git",
                    "type": "git",
                    "reference": "master"
                },
                "autoload": {
                    "classmap": ["/"]
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "ivantcholakov/gibberish-aes-php": "*@dev"
    }
}
```

As seen in the commtents a fresh composer install is sometimes needed after that.

Comment: Can you double check that? It still didn't generate any classmaps for me

Comment: try to make a fresh install that helped me

Comment: How weird, the clean install helped :p